# Snowflake sum two values between joined CTE's

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, addition

everyone.

I have a situation in Snowflake where I left join two CTE's together. The CTE on the left contains transaction data and well over 400k rows. The one on the right contains billing history data but only has just under 50K rows (not the issue though, I guess).

In both CTE's there is a REVENUE field. When joining I need to have either revenue value in that field, or A + B. Problem is some fields are fine, but where there are no records for the second CTE it also doesn't show the REVENUE. It should show something despite the left join. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'll paste the code below, but it's quite long. How do I get this to work?

```
with smartconnect_transactions as (
    select distinct
        dd.MONTHYEAR,
        date_trunc(month, tr.RECHARGEDATE) as MONTH,
        s.CREATE_DATE::date as ACTIVATION_DATE,
        s.TERMINATION_DATE::date as TERMINATION_DATE,
        s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        sum(tr.COST) over (partition by s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, date_trunc(month, tr.RECHARGEDATE)) as REVENUE,
        tr.MSISDN
    from UCONNECT_DW.ANALYTICS.VW_SC_TRANSACTION_REPORT as tr
    join UCONNECT_DW.ANALYTICS.DIM_SUBSCRIBERS as s
        on tr.MSISDN = s.PHONE_NUMBER
        and tr.RECHARGEDATE >= s.CREATE_DATE and tr.RECHARGEDATE < ifnull(s.TERMINATION_DATE, '2999-12-31')
    join UCONNECT_DW.ANALYTICS.DIM_DATE as dd
        on tr.RECHARGEDATE::date = dd.THEDATE
    where tr.RECHARGEDATE::date >= '2022-10-01'
        --and s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '17586662'
    group by
        dd.MONTHYEAR,
        s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        s.CREATE_DATE,
        s.TERMINATION_DATE,
        tr.RECHARGEDATE,
        tr.MSISDN,
        tr.COST
    order by MONTHYEAR, ACCOUNT_NUMBER),
smartconnect_billinghistory as (
    select distinct
        dd.MONTHYEAR,
        date_trunc(month, bh.ISSUEDDATE) as MONTH,
        s.CREATE_DATE::date as ACTIVATION_DATE,
        s.TERMINATION_DATE::date as TERMINATION_DATE,
        s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        sum(bh.COLLECTIONAMOUNT) over (partition by s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, date_trunc(month, bh.ISSUEDDATE)) as REVENUE,
        bh.MSISDN
    from UCONNECT_DW.ANALYTICS.VW_SC_SUBSCRIBER_BILLING_HISTORY as bh
    join UCONNECT_DW.ANALYTICS.DIM_SUBSCRIBERS as s
        on bh.MSISDN = s.PHONE_NUMBER
        and bh.ISSUEDDATE >= s.CREATE_DATE and bh.ISSUEDDATE < ifnull(s.TERMINATION_DATE, '2999-12-31')
    join UCONNECT_DW.ANALYTICS.DIM_DATE as dd
        on bh.ISSUEDDATE::date = dd.THEDATE
    where bh.ISSUEDDATE::date >= '2022-10-01'
    --and s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER::varchar = '17586662'
    group by
        dd.MONTHYEAR,
        s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        s.CREATE_DATE,
        s.TERMINATION_DATE,
        bh.ISSUEDDATE,
        bh.MSISDN,
        bh.COLLECTIONAMOUNT
    order by MONTHYEAR, ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
select distinct
    s.MONTHYEAR,
    s.ACTIVATION_DATE,
    s.TERMINATION_DATE,
    s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    s.REVENUE + bh.REVENUE as REVENUE
from smartconnect_transactions as s
left join smartconnect_billinghistory as bh
    on s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = bh.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    and s.MSISDN = bh.MSISDN
where s.REVENUE is not null;
```

Comment: Use zeroifnull around the bh.revenue column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A=10 and B=null,then for A+B Snowflake returns null, and the result value is null.. Use [COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce) to fix this.

```
select distinct
    s.MONTHYEAR,
    s.ACTIVATION_DATE,
    s.TERMINATION_DATE,
    s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    COALESCE(s.REVENUE + bh.REVENUE, s.REVENUE) as REVENUE
from smartconnect_transactions as s
left join smartconnect_billinghistory as bh
    on s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = bh.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    and s.MSISDN = bh.MSISDN
where s.REVENUE is not null;
```